# Display an image to be a certain size in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a number of different image URLs in my database, of varying dimensions. When I display my web page in PHP, how can I display the image and have it be fixed dimensions?

Comment: use css and style.
need more details

Comment: Hard code the dimensions in the `img` tag?

Comment: are you going to display images with <img > tag???

Comment: the output would be in html like <img src='mypic.jpg' height='100' />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using both fixed height and width will stretch the image. Use only one height or width in img tag or use css height or width to zoom image to fixed dimension.

1.) use either height or width in img tag in html
2.) use css either height or with
3.) resize image proportionately using image resize in php. for image resize you can use any 3rd party class. eg. suggested above.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know you could do this in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this easily: [Smart Image Resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I suggest resizing all images as they are uploaded and store the resized image along with the original.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a script like this (just an example code).

I recommend you to implement an image cache for resized files.

```
<?php

$image = "images/worldsmap_bg.png";

if(!file_exists($image))
    throw new Exception("file doesn't exists");

$imageinfo = getimagesize($image); 

$maxwidth = 120;
$maxheight = 150;
$origratio = $imageinfo[0]/$imageinfo[1];

$width = $imageinfo[0];
$height = $imageinfo[1];

if($height>$maxheight)
{
    $faktor = $maxheight/$imageinfo[1];
    if($faktor < 1)
    {
        $width = round($width*$faktor);
        $height = round($height*$faktor);
    }
}

if($width>$maxwidth)
{
    $faktor = $maxwidth/$width;
    if($faktor < 1)
    {
        $width = round($width*$faktor);
        $height = round($height*$faktor);
    }
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

switch($imageinfo[2]):
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000:
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception ("invalid image");
        break;
endswitch;


imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $imageinfo[0], $imageinfo[1]);

header("Content-type: " . image_type_to_mime_type($imageinfo[2]));

switch($imageinfo[2]):
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif($image_p);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000:
            imagejpeg($image_p);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng($image_p);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception ("invalid image");
        break;
endswitch;

?>
```